# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre deploy y puesta en producción de una aplicación o sitio web?

Tags: aplicación-web, ingenieria-del-software, arquitectura-de-software

Quisiera saber sí alguien podría sacarme la duda sobre esto, porque veo que los conceptos de deploy y producción son algo similares y no entiendo realmente la diferencia.

Ya que tengo los siguientes conceptos :

**Deploy** : Es llevar la aplicación, sitio web, sistema informático, desarrollado localmente y luego de haber hecho pruebas unitarias a un servidor para que pueda ser accedido las 24 horas.

**Producción** : Es similar al deploy pero luego de haber probado al 100% el desarrollo para que pueda ser accedido y utilizado por los clientes.

Comment: Para mi esta pregunta resulta ser util pese a ser basada en opiniones, por eso te di un voto arriba.

Answer (score 3):

Lo primero, Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español.

Aunque generalmente este tipo de preguntas son muy susceptibles a discusiones/debates (y generalmente terminan siendo cerradas, ver: [[help/dont-ask]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)), creo que es una pregunta interesante e intentaré compartir mi punto de vista:

**Deploy**: Este termino está referido a la “Actividad” como tal de “desplegar” (Ver su traducción literal del inglés). Es decir, la actividad de llevar cualquier aplicación/desarrollo a determinado ambiente.

La palabra como tal, no restringe al ambiente al que puedas/quieras llevar tu desarrollo. Por ejemplo, estaría bien decir “Voy a hacer deploy a producción” de la misma manera que está bien decir “Voy a hacer deploy a QA (Ambiente de pruebas)”.

Por su parte; “**Producción**” o ambiente productivo, es uno de los posibles “target” o “destinos” sobre los que puedes llevar tu “deploy” (Según la acepción dada en el punto anterior).

No obstante, “Llevar un sistema a producción” puede implicar mucho más que un simple despliegue (Deploy). Como bien lo comentas, pueda que requiera previamente un proceso de SQA (Aseguramiento de la calidad) /Pruebas, capacitación a los usuarios finales, pruebas de carga, etc.

Todo dependerá de la estrategia de `DevOps` (Término muy de moda) o la estrategia de Integración y despliegue continuo. Es decir, en desarrollos que están orientados al [agilismo](https://www.euroforum.es/blog/que-es-el-agilismo-y-por-que-tienes-que-conocerlo/), es muy deseable que se cuente con estrategias de integración y despliegue continuo (Son 2 por separado) … que permitan ir incrementando continuamente el valor del producto y acercar el `MVP` (Mínimo producto viable).

Lo más seguro es que encuentres en internet diferentes enfoques ya que existe un GRAN “DEPENDE…” allí.

Quizás estos links te sean de ayuda:

- [¿Sabes realmente qué es DevOps?](https://www.xeridia.com/blog/sabes-realmente-que-es-devops)
- [Continuous integration](https://aws.amazon.com/es/devops/continuous-integration/)
- [Integración, Entrega y despliegue continuo. Diferencias y similitudes](https://geeks.ms/jorge/2019/02/25/integracion-entrega-y-despliegue-continuo-diferencias-y-similitudes/)
- [Integracion continua ci- Entrega continua cd y despliegue continuo cd](https://devopsti.wordpress.com/2014/09/26/integracion-continua-ci-entrega-continua-cd-y-despliegue-continuo-cd/)
- [DevOps](http://blog.psyreactor.com.ar/devops/)